# how to detect state of bash readline using bash script?

Tags: shell-script, readline, vi-mode

for example;

```
if [ 'readline is vi-command' ]; then
  echo 'normal mode'
else
  echo 'insert mode'
fi
```

I really don't have any idea how to do this and I can't seem to find anything on the man pages either, or is it possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`vi-append-eol` (defaults to <kbd>A</kbd>) is only bound in command-mode.
Therefore, by querying if it is currently bound, the current mode
can be ascertained.

```
if LC_ALL=C bind -q vi-append-eol | grep -q 'not bound'; then 
  echo 'insert mode'
else
  echo 'normal mode'
fi
```

`LC_ALL=C` is used because in other locales "not bound" will be written in another language.

Of course, there is nothing special about `vi-append-eol`, there are a
bunch of other actions that are only bound in one of the modes, so any
of them can be used.